# list does not exist when I call spservices() / GetListItems

Tags: sharepoint-online, spservices

I'm starting to develop in SharePoint Online, but I don't arrive to do work `spservices()` with `GetListItems()`.

I have create an application with napacloudapp

In this application I have put that :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            webURL: "https://mycompagny.sharepoint.com/sites/test",
            listName: "Contacts",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
                    $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
                });
                alert(xData.responseText);                  
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

So when I run my project with my `alert(xData.responseText);` I can see

> "the List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."

I have added weburl parameter like Amal and bgmcoder said. Now in the console I have this error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Comment: Do you have a list in your site with the name Contacts?

Comment: Exactly do you have the list named contacts in your site??

Comment: Is the URL correct as per the last error? Does that web contains the list?

Comment: I have the list Contacts in my site. I go directly to the list since the url https://mycompagny.sharepoint.com/sites/test/List/Contacts/

Comment: @Mathi lists is under `/Lists/` not `/List/`

Comment: Anders > I have do that but that don't work, I'm come back at webURL : "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/test"

Comment: Please add your JQuery and SPServices script includes

Answer (score 2):

You might have to enable the Custom Script setting in Sharepoint Online.

The settings page is in Sharepoint Admin Settings - the url is like this:

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx
```

> Custom Script Control whether users can run custom script on personal
>   sites and self-service created sites.  Note: changes to this setting
>   might take up to 24 hours to take effect.
>
> For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=397546

These are the options:

- Prevent users from running custom script on personal sites
- Allow users to run custom script on personal sites

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the url of the site which has the list

```
webUrl: "http://weburl/"
```

Comment: I have already tried that in writting like weburl for example :
- "https://mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/sites/test" - "https://mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/sites/test/Lists/Contacts"
but without results, maybe it's not like that ?

Comment: @Mathi - you missed his point - he is giving you another parameter line to add into the spservices call.  You put it under `async: false,` in your code.  The `webUrl` is a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the webURL shouldn't look like this:

```
webURL: "https://mycompagny.sharepoint.com/sites/test",
```

My guess us that you really want

```
webURL: "/sites/test",
```

In other words, the webURL should be the relative path to the site where the list is located. However, you only need to specify the webURL if the list is not in the current context (site).

Comment: Marc, does it make a difference when it's `https`? Do the references to the JQuery and SPServices scripts also need the `https`, or should using relative links take care of this?